# From psychological point of view, how easy can public opinion be manipulated by politicians and media?

Tags: social-psychology, social-cognition

We have seen the Facebook–Cambridge Analytica data scandal in 2018 ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook%E2%80%93Cambridge_Analytica_data_scandal)). While I agree that stronger regulations on the use of personal data should be enforced, but from a psychological point of view:

1. How strongly can a person's political position be manipulated by a company like this (or combined with biased media)?
2. What kind of manipulation is possible and can be done? Can they completely reverse one's political position?